# SearchView and keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, searchview

I have an activity that has a SearchView directly above a ListView. The activity works by the user typing text in the SearchView which is then used to filter the content of the ListView.

On a 4" phone (Nexus 4) when the app is in "portrait" orientation and the user starts to input text in the search view, the lower half of the screen occupies the keyboard and the text is entered directly within the SearchView widget.

However, when the phone is in "landscape" orientation, the whole screen is occupied by the keyboard and a "text field" and the rest of the screen is lost. The "Search" button and the "Magnify glass" button on the keyboard seem to have no action.

See the screenshots[image]

Question

Is it possible to have the text entered directly in the SearchView widget when in landscape orientation?

If not, how do I make the buttons on the keyboard do something?

Comment: *Is it possible to have the text entered directly in the SearchView widget when in landscape orientation* - I don't think so. *how do I make the buttons on the keyboard do something?* - what buttons? what to do?

Comment: "The "Search" button and the "Magnify glass" button on the keyboard seem to have no action."

Comment: Sorry about that, I've totally missed that sentence. Are you sure you don't get the `onQueryTextSubmit` call when clicking on either search or the magnify button?

Answer (score 14):

You need to set your imeOptions for the SearchView widget, for example in the SearchableInfo xml:

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
```

Similar can be achieved via setImeOptions if your not using xml to configure your search view.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the imeOptions to an android.support.v7.widget.SearchView doesn't work: you'll need to set this at the EditText inside it:

Java:

```
EditText searchInput = searchview.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
searchInput.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH)
```

Kotlin:

```
val searchInput = searchview.findViewById<EditText>(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
searchInput.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
```

Comment: Can you please look at this question. I tried your solution but it didn't work in my case.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263084/android-search-tool-in-landscape-orientation

Comment: Using imeOptions in xml as in CCRoss answer in an android.support.v7.widget.SearchView works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from Java code like following, in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method:

```
searchView.setImeOptions(searchView.getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN);
```